# Delete Workspace user from AWS workspace directory?

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I'm new to AWS and I'm working on a project that uses the AWS Workspaces solution. I have created a test user via the Workspaces Management Console. I no longer need that user and I was wondering if there is a way to remove it from the directory. I can't seem to find anything related to deleting the users created by the Workspaces Management console other than that they cannot be deleted by using it. If there is any additional information that can provide more context please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

WorkSpaces use Directory Service directories. Other than resetting user passwords, Directory Service doesn’t provide for the management of users within the directory it creates. The documentation indicates that user management should be performed via standard AD management tools (MMC snap-in, PowerShell cmdlets, whatever you’d use for any other domain environment) by connecting to the domain controller. The WorkSpaces console (though strangely not the API) allows creating users but not deleting them, and while the WorkDocs API does have endpoints for user creation, deletion, etc. it appears those only work if the domain is set up with WorkDocs, which [you probably don't want to do](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/12021/39089) if you're not actually intending to use WorkDocs.